# Entity Framework Core assign foreign key constraint in OnModelCreating?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically generate my database using Entity Framework Core and I'm running into issues assigning a foreign key to a field in a table.  I need the field Address to reference the Address object and load it when I go to retrieve a record from the database.  If I create the database using `EnsureCreated`, it creates the tables correctly except that the field AddressId is not a foreign key to the Address table.  I have tried doing my research on this, and ran into [this article](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasforeignkey-method), which uses a method called `HasForeignKey`, however whatever is returning from Entity() doesn't know about `HasForeignKey`.  I get this error if I try manually typing it in I get:

> Error CS1061  'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a definition
>   for 'HasForeignKey' and no extension method 'HasForeignKey' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So obviously that approach isn't valid.  I tried following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints), but I don't really understand what it is doing and how to apply it to my situation.  In their case they have a couple tables, blog and posts, where blog has many posts and post has a blog.  I tried following along the best I could, but I don't really understand all the jargon and what it is accomplishing.

How can I go about simply assigning the value found in AddressId as a foreign key to a record in Addresses?  This is the code I am using.

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public byte Age { get; set; }
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source=test.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Address>().HasKey(v => v.Id);
            builder.Entity<Person>().HasKey(v => v.Id);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new MyContext())
            {
                //var person = db.People.Find(1);

                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var person = new Person()
                {
                    FirstName = "Jack",
                    LastName = "Jackson",
                    Age = 50,
                    Address = new Address()
                    {
                        Street = "123 Street St",
                        City = "Jacksonville",
                        State = "Mississippi",
                        ZipCode = "00000-0000"
                    }
                };

                db.People.Add(person);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

A little extra information:

- I am using .Net Core 2.0
- My database is SQLite
- I am using the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite & SQLite.Core libraries for my provider.

Comment: Your code should work as-is. If the constraint is not created on the SQLite database, it's most likely a bug in the provider

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the code does indeed work, but when I go to load the record the address field comes back as null, despite the AddressId field having a non-zero value.  I inspected the database in a DB Browser and there is nothing defining a foreign key constraint for that field.  I didn't specifically say this either, but this is a SQLite database (may or may not have been apparent, but it is defined as such in the OnConfiguring method).

Comment: Ahh, so the actual question is too hidden in this post. `Find` does not load related data, you need to use `db.Table.Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(x => x.SomeTable).SingleAsync()`

Comment: Good catch @CamiloTerevinto - but there is still his note that in the actual database table for Person, AddressId isn't a foreign key to Address...

Comment: Ah, that did it.  So previously I manually created my table, defined the foreign key constraint, and I was simply able to just do something like `db.People.Where(p => p.Id == Id).Single();` and it'd retrieve all the data for me without needing to call `Include`.  Is that just the way things are when working with the Fluent API?

Comment: Was that in EF6? Lazy loading of related entities just made it in to EF Core with 2.1

Comment: @G_P I'm using Entity Framework Core v2.0.3 currently.  If this is a feature with 2.1 I'll definitely look at what pain the upgrade may cause :-)

Answer (score 3):

In your OnModelCreating method try updating the following line to look like this (I wasn't able to test this code so my formatting may be off):

```
builder.Entity<Person>().HasOne(v => v.Address).WithMany().HasForeignKey(v => v.AddressId);
```

I believe that since you have the [Key] Data annotations in both entities, you don't need to set the key up via the Fluent API. Warning - I'm a bit new to EF Core too so I could be wrong. :)

Comment: Convention-over-configuration is the same in EF6 and EFCore. This shouldn't be required

Comment: I tried exactly t hat line before, and just now again, and after the `HasOne` part, the returning type doesn't know about HasForeignKey.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is getting old, since the documentation it pointed out helped me figure out a different problem I was going through myself, I'll post a solution for it down here.

There are two ways of solving this, one with a `ForeignKeyAttribute` annotation, another using the FluentAPI like you were using. You can set the Person to have one or multiple addresses, and the corresponding method changes according to that.

I also recommend making a Person property in the Address class, so you can use them the other way around as well.

The first is set in the Model class itself:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // The byte type is interpreted by EF as a boolean or BIT on SQL Server/Sqlite,
    // so I took the liberty of changing it to integer
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    // Set it to be a Collection of any type for a Person to be able to have multiple Addresses
    // public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }    

    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

The other, in case you want to tweak the constraint names, delete behaviors or other extra settings, you drop the ForeignKey attributes and do it with the Fluent API instead:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source=test.db");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(person =>
        {
            string tableName = "Persons";
            person.ToTable(tableName);
            person.HasKey(p => p.Id).HasConstraintName($"PK_{tableName}_Id");

            // In case you want to set your Id column to have an Identity/Autoincrement
            person.Property(p => p.Id).UseIdentityColumn();
            person.Property(p => p.FirstName).HasMaxLength(100);
            person.Property(p => p.LastName).HasMaxLength(250);

            // Replace HasOne by HasMany in case you want to make a Person
            // to be able to have multiple Addresses
            person.HasOne(p => p.Address).WithOne(a => a.Person).HasForeignKey("IdAddress").HasConstraintName($"FK_{tableName}_IdAddress").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>(address => {
            string tableName = "Addresses";
            address.ToTable(tableName);
            address.HasKey(a => a.Id).HasConstraintName($"PK_{tableName}_Id");

            // In case you want to set your Id column to have an Identity/Autoincrement
            address.Property(a => a.Id).UseIdentityColumn();
            address.Property(a => a.Street).HasMaxLength(50);
            address.Property(a => a.City).HasMaxLength(30);
            address.Property(a => a.State).HasMaxLength(30);
            address.Property(a => a.ZipCode).HasMaxLength(10);

            // Replace WithOne by WithMany in case you want to make a Person
            // to be able to have multiple addresses
            address.HasOne(a => a.Person).WithOne(p => p.Address).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `.WithOne(...)` returns a `ReferenceReferenceBuilder<TE, TRE>`. Since it's a 1-1 relationship, the FK can be on either type. So all `.HasForeignKey` overrides require you to specify the clr type or type name. Your fluent example `.HasForeignKey("IdAddress")` is calling `dependentEntityTypeName = "IdAddress", foreignKeyPropertyNames=new object[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but I hope someone can benefit from this answer. I experienced the same problem and it turned out I forgot to add the required nuget package. Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational and you'll be good to go.